# Updating localstorage arrays in Javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, local-storage

I'm trying to store and update an array in the localstorage using JSON.parse/stringify. But it doesn't seem to be working.

```
    yesArray = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem(yesArray));
    yesArray.push("yes");
    localStorage.setItem("yesArray", JSON.stringify(yesArray));
```

Am I all wrong with this?

Comment: What error do you see in console?

Comment: `getItem(yesArray)` -> `getItem("yesArray")` typo?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This seems to be the problem with passing the key of local storage without **quotes**.

While reading from local storage use the **key** as argument as it stores the value  as **key/value pairs**.

```
yesArray = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("yesArray"));
```

Answer (score 2):

Missing quotes around `yesArray` in the first line?

```
yesArray = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('yesArray'));
```

Sample:

```
var yesArray = [];
localStorage.setItem('yesArray', JSON.stringify(yesArray));
yesArray = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('yesArray'));
yesArray.push('yes');
localStorage.setItem('yesArray', JSON.stringify(yesArray));
JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('yesArray')); // Returns ["yes"]
```