# How can i save datas in a localStorage as a array?

Tags: html, arrays, local-storage

I need get inputs in html and save at the localStorage as a array or a json similar this:

[{"id":"item-1","icon":"google.com"},{"id":"item-2","icon":"youtube.com"}]

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Questions seeking code help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself preferably in a [Stack Snippet](https://stackoverflow.blog/2014/09/16/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/?more_on=xron.net). See How to create a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). It also very helpful to show in your Question an expected result, and quote any (exact) errors you are getting. You are expected to show any research you have put into solving this question yourself.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Updating localstorage arrays in Javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40985620/updating-localstorage-arrays-in-javascript)

Answer (score 1):

Did you even search?

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage

```
localStorage.setItem('myData', '[{"id":"item-1","icon":"google.com"},{"id":"item-2","icon":"youtube.com"}]');
```

Answer (score 0):

`localStorage` only supports string values.
You can use `JSON.stringify()` and `JSON.parse()` to set and get data from `localStorage`

```
    const names = ["josh", "nick"]
    localStorage.setItem("names", JSON.stringify(names))
    const localStorageNames = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("names"))
```