# Using localStorage trying to set an array value not able to update or delete array value

Tags: javascript, reactjs, local-storage, mobx, mobx-react

I have to select few elements from UI and then need to store the id of each selected in the localstorage. When user will deselect it , then that value from localstorage should also be removed . for that which I did

```
 @observable marks = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('marks')) || [];

    @action handleChange = Mid => {
      let getMarks =  JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('marks')) || [];
      let foundIndex = getMarks.indexOf(Mid)
      if (foundIndex > -1) {
        remove(getMarks, id => id === Mid)
      } else {
        localStorage.setItem('marks', JSON.stringify([Mid]))
      }
  }
```

Here, localStorage adds the only recent value and while and also not getting set to the `observable` which I am using it to render .

How do I fix this ?

Thanks.

Updated fix

```
@action handleChange = Mid => {
    let foundIndex = this.marks.indexOf(Mid)
    if (foundIndex > -1) {
      remove(this.marks, id => id === Mid)
      localStorage.setItem('marks', JSON.stringify(this.marks))
    } else {
      this.marks.push(Mid)
      localStorage.setItem('marks', JSON.stringify(this.Mid))
    }
  }
```

Comment: `localStorage.removeItem('marks')` will remove the item. Here's an example of how to update a value in an array stored in localStorage: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40985620/updating-localstorage-arrays-in-javascript

Answer (score 0):

To add new item you want to push it into the existing array. Instead you are creating a new array with one element and ignoring anything that was previously stored

Change:

```
localStorage.setItem('marks', JSON.stringify([Mid]))
```

To

```
getMarks.push(Mid)
localStorage.setItem('marks', JSON.stringify(getMarks))
```

Comment: what about removing the item?

Comment: You said you had that working but didn't show your code for your `remove()` function. Could do `getMarks=getMarks.filter(id => id !== Mid)` and stringify the whole array agin in setItem

Comment: Please check what I have done in the question, this will also update the value of this.marks. with the latest value ?